# I have a problem in my app ionic 3,when i add ionic cordova resources add android to the use of app icon I have this error :

Tags: ionic3, ionic4, ionic-cli

I have a problem in my app ionic 3,when I add ionic cordova resources add android to the use of app icon I have this error :

> [ERROR] cordova-res was not found on your PATH. Please install it globally:

Answer (score 0):

run 
npm install -g cordova-res
ionic cordova resources --cordova-res